# How do you restore old users, jobs, and configuration in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am a new Jenkins user who is trying to be an administrator. I was trying to reload Jenkins to resolve an issue with Extent Reports not displaying properly. I shut down Jenkins and passed this command upon restart from the command console:

`java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="" -jar jenkins.war`

Upon restart, Jenkins loaded up a whole new configuration and all my users, jobs, etc., are gone. There is no backup folder, but I can see the user files and the old jobs there.

Is there any way that I can restore, import, what have you, to get my stuff back or am I pretty much screwed and will have to create all this stuff from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use the job import plugin and let me know if it worked. Also the fix for you Extent report , you didnt have to run that command. There is actually one line of script that you should run within jenkins and will fix the issue. [Job Import Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin)

To fix Extent Report:
You need to change default Content Security Policy go to Manage Jenkins -> Script Console and type into console the following commands:

System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP");

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *");

Then try to the view Web Report again.

Comment: Here's an update. Maybe all I need to do is restore the `JENKINS_HOME` location. Right not, it is showing a .`jenkins` folder in my user directory. It needs to be `C:\Program Files\Jenkins\`. I do not know how or why this changed. I am trying to change the home location without any luck. If you know, could you share this info with me? I am running on a WIndows Server if that makes any difference.

Comment: Disregard.... The real problem was that I was starting from WAR instead of starting the Windows Service. Once I restarted the service, all my old stuff loaded correctly.  That was quite a scare, but I thank you for the information. It is still very valuable for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Glad that you found the solution.